# Using bash convert a JSON file to JSON Object

Tags: json, shell

I have a JSON File as follows :

```
{
 "IP Address" : " 192.168.43.221 ",
 "OS ":" Ubuntu ",
 "OS Version ": " 16.04.4 ",
 "OS Installed Data ": " Dec 8 23:59 ",
 "Model name ": " AMDA10-5750MAPU with Radeon(tm)HD ",
 "MemTotal ": " 5275728kB ",
 "Hard disk capacity ": " [1.00TB] ", 
 "Users ": " ananth "
}
```

I want to convert the above JSON File into JSON Object only using shell scripting? Can someone help me to do this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think a "JSON object" is, in this context? The whole concept of an "object" only makes sense in the context of runtime storage in the memory of a runtime that *has* some kind of object-oriented representation/abstraction.

Comment: What do you mean, "given JS"? Do you mean you have some JavaScript code you want to evaluate that object against? Then this is a question about a JavaScript runtime (node.js or whichever other one you're using), not about bash. BTW, for general purposes related to extracting content from JSON for shell use, I'd suggest [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), being the common/accepted tool for the job.

Comment: My requirement is to send the system information to WebApi and I gathered that information and generated to a JSON file. But every one hour it has to be verified for any updates/changes.so I attached that script file to _crontab_  and I thought that object is required for verifying updates in that information.

Comment: A JSON "object" doesn't have a different serialization mechanism than the bytes in a JSON "file" -- in terms of how you send them over the wire to an API, it's the same thing either way.

Comment: I need to verify the changes/updates for every successive JSON Files. I thought that it would be easier if I have Objects than compared to JSON Files.

Comment: The above _is_ a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is valid as JSON text, as can for example be verified by pasting the contents into https://jsonlint.com

One way to "load" the JSON file into a javascript interpreter would be as follows.  For the sake of specificity, assume the interpreter is v8 or js (JavaScript-C). First, copy the file while prepending something like "x=", e.g.

```
(echo "x="; cat input.json) > input.js
```

Now, after starting v8 or js, run: `load("input.js")`

The variable `x` will then contain the JSON object.

If you want to trim the key names so that they do not have exterior spaces, you could, for example, run the following [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command:

```
jq 'with_entries(.key|=(sub("^ +";"")|sub(" +$";"")))' input.json
```

#### Object Equality

Based on some comments, it appears you want to check whether the JSON objects in two files are "equal" in the sense of object-equality.

This can be done in a variety of ways.  One simple and tidy way would be to use jq as follows:

```
jq -s '.[0] == .[1]' file1.json file2.json
```

An alternative would be to write the files in a "canonical" (i.e., normalized) way so that a text-oriented tool such as `diff` can be used, e.g.

```
jq -S . file1.json | sponge file1.json
jq -S . file2.json | sponge file2.json
```

The -S option causes the keys to be sorted in a fixed order; `sponge` is inessential here but convenient.

Comment: Very thanks for taking your time and answering. But I do not want to use any other packages such as _jq_. I want to convert the given type JSON file into JSON Object

Comment: As already mentioned, it is a JSON object already. If you want a "canonical" textual representation of the JSON text, then again a tool like jq is perfect.  You can also use jq to compare two JSON files to see if they represent the same JSON object (in the sense of object-equality).